# Is there a way for a discord bot to respond to a mention of a specific user using Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I would like my bot to be able to reply to a mention of a specific user (ex.. one person mentions my personal account and the bot responds saying that I'm currently not here)

Is there a way to do this using a format similar to this?

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('@user_id'):
        await message.channel.send('Im not here leave a message!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the specific format that discord bots receive mentions. The format is <@!user_id>.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if ("<@!put user id here>" in message.content):
        await message.channel.send("Im not here leave a message!")
```

Example for how applied this and it worked for me

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if ("<@!348256959671173120>" in message.content):
        await message.channel.send("Im not here leave a message!")
```

Comment: ok so, I reworked my program to follow this format and still nada is it possible this is an outdated format or is there more to this?

Comment: I removed the f string and the curly brackets and posted exactly what I used in order for it work underneath. You can possibly try this.

Answer (score 0):

Discord [Member objects](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) have a [`.mentioned_in(message)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mentioned_in) method.

```py
WIZARD_ID = 123456 # <- replace with user ID you want
async def on_message(message):
    wizard_of_oz = message.guild.get_member(WIZARD_ID)
    if wizard_of_oz.mentioned_in(message):
         await message.channel.send("Who dares summon the great Wizard of OZ?!")
```

If you also want to condition on if the user is mentioned by *role* you need to check the role_mentions in the message, too. So a more complete example is as follows:

```py
def was_mentioned_in(message: discord.Message, member: discord.Member) -> bool:
    """
    Whether or not the member (or a role the member has) was mentioned in a message.
    """
    if member.mentioned_in(message):
        return True
    for role in message.role_mentions:
        if role in member.roles:
            return True
    return False

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    wizard_of_oz = message.guild.get_member(WIZARD_ID)
    if was_mentioned_in(message, wizard_of_oz):
         await message.channel.send("Who dares summon the great Wizard of OZ?!")
```